# Runtime Error with background script in Dhis2 Tabular Tracker Capture

Tags: dhis2

I faced this issue on Friday evening, when I added new client and I tried to edit her profile. Then I hit run to list client windows as usual however there was no data showing. I captured screen and attached below.[image]

Comment: Sorry but as it stands the question is too specific and unlikely to help others in its current format. Furthermore JavaScript related problems are best suited on Stack Overflow but again, the format would be an issue for migrating. Please visit Stack Overflow and visit their help centre before reposting to avoid further disappointment.